# How to dualize some rows conditionally in the SELECT's result?

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say we have a table in a MySQL database, which has this two text columns `mime_type` and `file_name`. I could to `SELECT` a data from this table in such a manner:

```
id  mime_type           file_name
001 application/pdf     file_one.pdf
002 image/png           screenshot.png
002 image/png           thumb_screenshot.png      # <- This row is "virtual"
...
```

I.e. depending on a contents of the `mime_type` column (for image files) add a nonexistent actually in the table row with the same data, but with slightly changed `file_name`'s value.

Is there some way to do this using SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `union all`:

```
select id, mime_type, file_name
from t
union all
select id, mime_type, 'thumb_screenshot.png'
from t
where mime_type = 'image/png';
```

EDIT:

Based on the comment:

```
select id, mime_type, file_name
from t
union all
select id, mime_type, concat('thumb_', file_name)
from t
where mime_type = 'image/png';
```

Comment: The 'screenshot.png' here is an example only. Actually I need to prefix any value of the `file_name` with the 'thumb_', but for images only (depending on the `mime_type`'s value).